# Getting root node from char array libxml2

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

I am able to read a xml from a file 
eg.

```
xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
xmlNode *root = NULL;
doc = xmlReadFile("config.xml", NULL, 0);
root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
```

But i want to read the XML from a char array not a file 
can please any one tell me how to do it, example would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of xmlReadFile, use xmlReadMemory

http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadMemory

```
xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
xmlNode *root = NULL;
char *xml = "<node/>";
doc = xmlReadMemory(xml, strlen(xml), NULL, NULL, 0);
root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
```